# Join multiple column with single row using

Tags: mysql

```
I have a query which results in single row like: (table_1)

        | col_1 | col_2 | col_3 |
row->1  | A     | B     | C     |
```

Another query results in two rows like: (table_2)

```
        | col_1 | col_2 |
row->1  | A     | X     |
row->2  | A     | Y     |
```

Common value for both table is col_1(A). What I need is like:

```
|   col_1   |   col_2   |   col_3   |   col_4   |   col_5   |
|   A       |   B       |   C       |   X       |   Y       |
```

Please provide the simplest way to achive this.

Comment: It seems like an exercice from a lecture. We are not here to provide solution for you school ...

Comment: What did you try? Also provide the details regarding the error/non-required behavior.

Comment: Post what you have already done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can try it-

```
SELECT a.col_1,a.col_2,a.col_3, 
(SELECT b.col_2 FROM table2 AS b WHERE b.col_1=a.col_1 LIMIT 1) as col_4, 
(SELECT b.col_2 FROM table2 AS b WHERE b.col_1=a.col_1 LIMIT 1,1) as col_5 
FROM table1;
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @Zafar Malik. I don't think those people who are asking some kind of doubts here are all extra experts or genius.Sometime a beginner like me do have the right to ask what seem to be a silly question to some people. Please encourage them.